# Searching for location in nature through PDOK

Tags: maps

I am developing an application where the requirement is to search (by typing in or clicking on the map) for the various locations in the Netherlands. I have a PDOK locatieserver successfully integrated for addresses and various public places, but the problem I am facing is on how to process locations for places which do not have an address.

How would one code a map that would be able to geocode an address to lat/long coordinates but at the same time also support various locations like specific points on lakes, rivers or in forests? By geocoding I mean that the app should return something when clicking on the lake, like it's name for instance and it's location (province, city, postalcode). Lake was just an example, it would be great that it returns name of the place when clicking on anything on the map.

My current solution for addresses is that the code calls `https://api.pdok.nl/bzk/locatieserver/search/v3_1/suggest` with the query and then `https://api.pdok.nl/bzk/locatieserver/search/v3_1/lookup` to get the location's details. But this does not work for various places that do not have an address.